# perl: how to check if url link is not 404

Tags: perl

I was wondering how to check url link in perl? I want to know if it is invalid link.

Also, I would like to know how to authenticate with username and password when checking url links.

Comment: Please give examples, preferably working ones. What libraries are you using? Use `LWP` to read from any URL and check the `credentials` by accessing the header instead of the entire resource

Answer (score 7):

See [method `credentials` in LWP::UserAgent](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent#ua-credentials-netloc-realm-) and [method `is_success` in HTTP::Response](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Response#r-is_success).

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw();
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->credentials('hostname.example:80', 'realm name', 'login', 'password')
my $res = $ua->head('http://hostname.example/fullurl');
$res->is_success;
# $res->is_error
# $res->is_redirect
## specific status code comparison:
# $res->code != HTTP::Status::HTTP_NOT_FOUND()
```

You probably want to upgrade to [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize) to follow redirects automatically and easier authentification.

Comment: You don't need Mech to follow redirects, except for the "meta tag" kind. In fact, LWP follows them by default.

Comment: @hobbs: agreed. WWW::Mechanize is unnecessary and a huge overhead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `LWP::Simple` and do a `HEAD` request

From this [link](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/08/20/perlandlwp.html)

> There are other useful functions in LWP::Simple, including one
>   function for running a HEAD request on a URL (useful for checking
>   links,

And from the [rfc](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
>   return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained
>   in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical
>   to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can
>   be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the
>   request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is
>   often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility,
>   and recent modification.

Answer (score 0):

use LWP; you can find it on CPAN here:
https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP